# Is Thompson's group $T$ co-Hopfian?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

A group $G$ is *co-Hopfian* if every injective homomorphism $G\to G$ is bijective, i.e., if $G$ contains no proper subgroups isomorphic to $G$. My question is whether Thompson's group $T$ is co-Hopfian.

For context, Thompson's groups $F$ and $V$ are very much not co-Hopfian, roughly due to the fact that there are many copies of the unit interval inside the unit interval, and many copies of the Cantor set inside the Cantor set. However, there are no copies of the circle properly inside the circle, so the same intuition does not apply to $T$.

Comment: Le Boudec and Matte Bon proved (Ann ENS 2018, https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.01651) that  every nontrivial continuous action of $T$ on the circle is semiconjugate to the standard action. This might be a step towards a positive answer.

Comment: I am a bit confused with the remark that there is no copies of the circle sitting inside the circle. Since $\mathbb{T}\cong \mathbb{R}\oplus \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, we can choose a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ isomorphic to itself, Is this something too naive?

Comment: Bombyx mori, unfortunately $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is co-Hopfian, so that won't work. By "no copies of the circle in the circle" I meant that no proper subspace of the circle is homeomorphic to the circle (unlike the situation for the interval or the Cantor set).

Comment: The inclusion of the centralizer in $T$ of a rotation through $2\pi/n$ is `close' to showing that $T$ is non-co-Hopfian: isn't this subgroup isomorphic to a (presumably non-split) central extension with kernel $C_n$ and quotient $T$?

Comment: IJL - I think that is right, and seems to correspond to the finite-sheeted covers $S^1 \to S^1$ in the same way that the universal cover $\mathbb{R}\to S^1$ produces the central extension often called $\widetilde{T}$. Like you said none of these are split though, so, too bad (but yes, this is quite close).

Comment: By the way I've received an email, from a reliable source, with a proof that $T$ is not co-Hopfian, but I want to be 100% sure it works before publicly declaring the problem solved.

Comment: @MattZaremsky: Would the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is not co-Hopfian help? Thanks for the clarification, though.

Comment: @MattZaremsky Does you email tell you a little about the construction. In particular, it yields a new action of $T$ on the circle (by composition): is this new action minimal?

Comment: Besides, I'm not sure I can tell whether the subgroup of $T$ of elements whose slopes are in $4^\mathbf{Z}$ is isomorphic to $T$.

Comment: Bombyx mori - Ah, right, I guess the circle does properly contain itself group theoretically, if not topologically. But T acts by homeomorphisms on the circle so changing the topology seems dangerous. Yves - The claimed construction yields a non-minimal action, which is how you know the endomorphism is not surjective. I think by Monday I'll have convinced myself it works. As for the 4-ary version of T, good question, I don't know off the top of my head that it's not isomorphic to T (but it really shouldn't be....)

Comment: Am I right if I say that $T_2$ is a subgroup of $T_4$ and that $T_4$ is also a subgroup of $T_2$?

Comment: @AGenevois - Certainly $T_4$ embeds in $T_2$, and it feels like $T_2$ really ought to embed in $T_4$, but last week I could neither confirm this nor find it anywhere in the literature (it is kind of hard to google things like this though). Should be true though....

Comment: By the way if $T_2$ embeds into $T_4$, this would most likely eventually lead to a mechanical verification proof that $T_2$ is non-cohopfian. More precisely, assuming that the homomorphism is known in terms of generators, where $T_4$ is explicitly given as generated by a finite subset $S$ (either with an presentation of $T_4$ over $S$, or with an explicit embedding of $S$ into $T_2$), this just consists in checking that the given images of generators of $T_2$ satisfying the defining relators of $T_2$.

Comment: I realized that $T_2$ does not in fact embed into $T_4$! This is because $T_4$ has no elements of order 3. More generally for any $n>2$, $T_n$ has no elements of order $n-1$. The fastest way I can see this is, under the action of $T_n$ on its CAT(0) Stein-Farley cube complex, any finite order element must fix a vertex, and the vertex stabilizers are all cyclic of order congruent to 1 mod $n-1$.

Comment: Recording this here in case it's ever useful to anyone: I realized that the non-co-Hopfian-ness of $T$ can be easily deduced from a paper of Belk and Forrest: https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.4225. They construct a group $T_B$ such that $T_B$ embeds into $T$ (Remark 5.5), $T$ embeds into $T_B$ (Remark 6.5), and $T_B$ is not isomorphic to $T$ (for example $T_B$ is not simple, see Corollary 8.2).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer to the question is no, $T$ is not co-Hopfian, i.e., it does contain proper subgroups isomorphic to itself. Nicolás Matte Bon explained this to me over email (he doesn't use Mathoverflow, but someone showed him this question).

Matte Bon's strategy is to look at $T$ acting on the Cantor set $C=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and define a new (faithful) action of $T$ on $C$ that yields an (injective) endomorphism $T\to T$ (and then argue that it is not surjective). For non-surjectivity, the idea is that under the new action there is a proper non-empty invariant open subset (so the action is not minimal), unlike for the usual action of $T$. Constructing such an action is a bit too complicated to explain here, but it uses ideas from Section 11 of Matte Bon's paper [1]. What I can do here is explain one concrete example of a proper endomorphism $T\to T$, which I sorted out after understanding Matte Bon's general construction.

To describe the endomorphism $T\to T$, I will use the strand diagram model for elements of $T$ (and $F$ and $V$), see, e.g., Definition 2.7 of Belk-Matucci [2]. For each split or merge vertex (Definition 2.1(2)), draw a small neighborhood around the vertex, not meeting any other vertices. For a split this neighborhood has one incoming strand and two outgoing strands, and for a merge this neighborhood has two incoming strands and one outgoing strand. Now to define $T\to T$ we replace the picture inside each such neighborhood with a more complicated picture. For a split, replace the strand going from the split vertex to the right exit with the picture in Figure 2 of Belk-Matucci (the usual "$x_0$" generator). For a merge, do this same thing but flipped upside-down. (Don't change any cyclic permutations.) This defines a well defined injective endomorphism $T\to T$ (if we only allow cyclic permutations that is; if we allow all permutations then it's $V\to V$, and if we allow no permutations then it's $F\to F$). To see it's non-surjective, one can use the strand diagram method of analyzing dynamics (see, e.g., Figure 19 of Belk-Matucci) to check that if $f$ is in the image of this endomorphism and $c\in C$ starts with $11$ then $f(c)$ has a "$11$" somewhere in it. (Since $T$ certainly contains elements violating this rule, this gives non-surjectivity.)

[1] Nicolás Matte Bon, *Rigidity properties of full groups of pseudogroups over the Cantor set*. [arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.10133)

[2] James Belk, Francesco Matucci, *Conjugacy and dynamics in Thompson's groups.* Geometriae Dedicata 169.1 (2014) 239-261. [arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.4250)

Comment: At least to define the endomorphism should be computer-checkable, since it consists in defining images of generators and checking they satisfy the defining relators (once a presentation of $T$ is fixed). Since generators map to nontrivial elements the endomorphism is non-constant, and hence injective by simplicity of $T$. (Then remains the non-surjectivity.)

Comment: An optimistic improvement would be to use the results of Matte Bon's paper [1] to completely classify endomorphisms of $T$ (modulo post-composition by conjugation).

Comment: True, $T$ has a nice small presentation with 3 generators and 6 relations (somewhere in Cannon-Floyd-Parry) so this might not be too tedious. And yeah, that could be interesting to classify the endos, and maybe not too unreasonable....